# Pros and Cons of Keep-Alive from Web Server Side

Tags: web-server, performance, http, keepalive

Keep-Alive connection feature in HTTP protocol is meant to reduce TCP connection hits to web server. It should be able to improve web server performance. However, I found that some web servers deliberately disable KeepAlive feature from server side.

In my understanding, some reverse proxy, i.e. HAProxy, disables HTTP keep-alive in order to reduce memory usage which is more critical than CPU usage in some situation.

Is there any other reason why Web server disables Keep-Alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep alive is meant to reduce the number of tcp-setups, which are chatty and are heavily influenced by latency. It's main goal is to improve client performance - as for a modern server-os there is a low cost in setting up tcp connections.

Some proxies/loadbalancers lean disable keep-alive to the webservers because they assume the actual servers and are on a LAN with neglible latency, and therefore neglible tcp setup penalty.
It also lessens the complexity of the balancing software, as there is not necessarily a one-to-one relationship between incomming and outgoing (from the LB's perspective) connections.

There are few reasons why a server would disable keep-alive, so I suspect it's probably admins at fault. One exception are the a-child-per-connection servers (apache), where releasing that child/thread as soon as possible offers advantages, even if the total browser experience (and bandwidth usage) becomes poorer.

Note that afaik keep-alive is an optional feature and no service is required to implement it.

Comment: NGINX allows keepalive on the server side. However it allows you to specify the limit of keep alive connections. How do we calculate how many connections is optimal?